# What subset of errors can be expected from a call to Stripe.card.createToken()?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, stripe-payments

When making a call to `Stripe.card.createToken()` (Stripe.js) it seems that only a subset of the errors described in the [api docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors) could be returned. Some errors, like `card_error/card_declined`, could only (?) be returned from a server side call to `charge` a card.

What error types and codes can be expected when making a client side call to `Stripe.card.createToken()`?

https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Checkout, Stripe.js only does a basic set of validations on a card such as a Luhn check and whether the expiration is with the valid universe.

You will see a `card_error` if, for example, the expiration or card properties are invalid, `invalid_request_error` should you attempt to send invalid parameters to the API, a connection error if there were a time out between your client and Stripe.

But your understanding is correct here, you would never see a decline as (unlike Checkout) an authorization is not attempted until the time at which you add the card to a Customer or create a Charge on your backend.